# Availability group listener is not listening

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, listener

I've successfully created an availability group with 3 nodes. I've tried to create a listener, separately trying port 1433 and 1435, but the listener is not even trying to listen - there's no entry in `sys.dm_tcp_listener_states`, and nothing in `netstat -abn`. I don't know how to begin debugging this.

`SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tcp_listener_states`:

```
listener_id  ip_address  is_ipv4  port  type  type_desc           state  state_desc  start_time
5            ::          0        4607  2     DATABASE_MIRRORING  0      ONLINE      2018-06-18 14:35:16.220
6            0.0.0.0     1        4607  2     DATABASE_MIRRORING  0      ONLINE      2018-06-18 14:35:16.220
3            ::1         0        1434  0     TSQL                0      ONLINE      2018-06-18 14:35:15.533
4            127.0.0.1   1        1434  0     TSQL                0      ONLINE      2018-06-18 14:35:15.533
1            ::          0        1433  0     TSQL                0      ONLINE      2018-06-18 14:35:15.533
2            0.0.0.0     1        1433  0     TSQL                0      ONLINE      2018-06-18 14:35:15.533
```

`netstat -abn | findstr "143"`:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    127.0.0.1:1434         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    [::]:1433              [::]:0                 LISTENING
TCP    [::1]:1434             [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

Comment: Have you looked at your cluster logs? How about WSFC manager? Is there a AG role and do you see any listener objects. Are there any errors? SQL Server? Cluster?

Comment: Does your listener exist as an Active Directory Object? Each availability group listener requires a DNS host name that is unique in the domain and in NetBIOS.

Comment: have you tried to ping the IP you assigned to it?